# Why must this be passed in as an Array and not a String?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm following a node.js tutorial from a book called Node Web Developments.

**Problem:** In one part of the code, an array `[]` containing HTML code is passed from `mult-node.js` into the required function `htutil.page()` as the 3rd argument, and the 2 values returned by `exports.navbar()` and `exports.page()` in `htutil.js` but I cannot figure out why it must be an array and not a long string? I don't see any code in `htutil.page()` that extracts the array into a long string where it will be displayed on a HTML page.

**htutil.js**

```
var url = require('url');

exports.loadParams = function(req, res, next) {
    req.requrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
    req.a = (req.requrl.query.a && !isNaN(req.requrl.query.a))
        ? new Number(req.requrl.query.a)
        : NaN;
    req.b = (req.requrl.query.b && !isNaN(req.requrl.query.b))
        ? new Number(req.requrl.query.b)
        : NaN;
        if(next) next();
}

exports.navbar = function() {
    return ["<div class='navbar'>",
            "<p><a href='/'>Home</a></p>",
            "<p><a href='/mult'>Multiplication</a></p>",
            "<p><a href='/square'>Square's</a></p>",
            "<p><a href='/factorial'>Factorial's</a></p>",
            "<p><a href='/fibonacci'>Fibonancci's</a></p>".
            "</div>"].join('\n');
}

exports.page = function(title, navbar, content) {
    return ["<html><head><title>{title}</title></head>",
            "<body><h1>{title}</h1>",
            "<table><tr>",
            "<td>{navbar}</td><td>{content}</td>",
            "</tr></table></body></html>"].join('\n');
            .replace("{title}", title, "g")
            .replace("{navbar}", navbar, "g")
            .replace("{content}", content, "g");
}
```

**mult-node.js**

```
var htutil = require('./htutil');
exports.get = function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead('200', {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    var result = req.a * req.b;
    res.end(
        // THIS IS THE FUNCTION WHERE THE ARRAY OF HTML CODE IS PASSED INTO
        htutil.page('Multiplication', htutil.navbar(), [
            (!isNaN(req.a) && !isNaN(req.b) ?
                ("<p class='result'>{a} * {b} = {result}</p>"
                .replace('{a}', req.a)
                .replace('{b}', req.b)
                .replace('{result}', req.a * req.b))
                : ""),
            "<p>Enter numbers to multiply</p>",
            "<form name='mult' action='/mult' method='get'>",
            "A: <input type='text' name='a' /><br>",
            "B: <input type='text' name='b' />",
            "<input type='submit' value='Submit' />",
            "</form>"
            ].join('\n'))
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see it's not passing an array - it's joining it into a string before passing it in.

The reason for this is that string joining is (at least supposedly) more efficient than repeated concatenation, this of course depends on the implementation of `join`, but I'd imagine most implementations optimize it. JavaScript doesn't have a StringBuffer or a StringBuilder type, so joining an array is the closest thing you get.

Comment: doesnt enclosing the HTML in square braces `[...]` turn the strings seperated by colons into an array?

Comment: @Nyxynyx: Yes, but the `.join('\n')` call at the end turns the array into a string.